# How to set an icon for a frame in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have used this statement to set icon of a frame:

```
frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("tictactoe.gif"));
```

Unfortunately the frame icon still shows default `java` icon instead.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Check if `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("tictactoe.gif")` really reads the image. Try to split into 2 lines:

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("tictactoe.gif");
frame.setIconImage (img);
```

Then use debugger to check what is there inside `img` variable.

Comment: Roman is right, your code is correct, but the path to the gif probably wrong. getImage will likely return null and thus the setting of the icon will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [ImageIcon](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) and let us now if it works:-). It has a simple constructor taking a path to file with icon image. After construction you can retrieve image from it by calling ImageIcon.getImage().

Maybe the image is not in the right place and cannot be found?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. To retrieve Image from it you additionally need to call getImage().