# Modifying taskbar icon of my .jar program

Tags: java, jar, icons, size, taskbar

I'm trying to change the default java icon that appears in taskbar everytime I run my .jar program. I managed to change it with frame.setIconImage(img); but this makes icon way too small, I want it to be as big as other programs icons and have a high quality. Any way I can do that? Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming the image you're using is the right size (standard for Windows 7 is 256x256). Just checking :)

Comment: I checked the size of image and it was 256x256 but it had transparent areas around it so that was the problem. But it still is pretty bad quality icon. Any ideas for that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `bad quality icon`. Is it small, or is it pixilated? Sorry, I've never done this before, so I'm shooting in the blind.

Comment: I got size working but it is still pixelated

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370526/setting-an-icon-for-a-frame)

Comment: You're on Windows, right?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you only supplied a **single** icon, Windows will then *scale* that icon to whatever size it needs displaying it in the taskbar (could be 16x16, 32x32 or other sizes, depending on the desktop them and size of the taskbar.

If you want to have a "good looking" icon in the task bar you will need to provide a 32x32 pixel version of your icon.

Once you have that you can call [`setIconImages(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages%28java.util.List%29) instead of `setIconImage()` to define the icons that the operating system can use:

```
List<Image> icons = new ArrayList<Image>();
icons.add(getImage("someImage16x16.gif"));
icons.add(getImage("someImage32x32.gif"));
window.setIconImages(icons);
```

Where `getImage()` is some method returning the proper image icon. Essentially that would be the same steps you already used to define the current icon.

You can also supply a 64x64 and 24x24 icon using this method (just add more icons to the list).

Comment: Excellent. Very simple to understand and works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I read somewhere (ambiguous, I know, but I forgot where) that the standard is 256x256 (not totally sure why). Because there's a handy method for handing it a list of Images, you may want to include one that's bigger too. Just a thought :)

Answer (score 4):

Try looking at [this example](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/SettingIconFrame.shtml). It looks like you need to use `frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("your_image.gif"));` line