# Java read file within .exe program

Tags: java, file, exe

I generated an .exe file from my jar using Launch4j. 
I was using ZipInputStream to read files inside my .jar before but now it is not working anymore (`zip.getNextEntry()` returns null).

The only solution I found was to drop the .exe and use a Runnable jar instead. Is it the only solution though ?

Comment: You should be using `Class.getResourceAsStream` to load resources.

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase what I mean: how to browser the file inside the .exe to get their name ?

Comment: Use a library like [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) to do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you use a .exe? Do you have to? Otherwise just provide a .bat file which executes the java command to start the jar.

Put this into myapp.bat

> start javaw -jar myapp.jar

see [Run .jar from batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622062/run-jar-from-batch-file)

Comment: Its rather for aestetic purpose: having a custom icon for my application and a custom one in the task bar since my program is for a video game

Comment: You can change the icon in the task bar afaik and provide an icon for your .bat file too. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575541/modifying-taskbar-icon-of-my-jar-program and in general you don't want to ship your java app as .exe except you will provide your own jre. Otherwise you still need java installed.

Comment: If you are going to do that, I'd look at using Java Web Start rather than a bat file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453369/i-have-never-seen-a-software-be-released-as-jar-so-how-can-i-make-a-software-be/1453477#1453477